# Aubio 0.4.0 Python Windows Installed but failing when creating aubio source

Tags: python, gcc, numpy, libav, aubio

So I managed to get aubio 0.4.0 installed so that it imports into python without errors however I haven't figured out how to pass files to be analyzed.

Here's the steps I've done to install aubio 0.4.0 taken from [here](https://lists.aubio.org/pipermail/aubio-user/2014-January/000178.html):

- Downloaded the most recent git build of Aubio 0.4.0 source download - http://git.aubio.org/
- Unpacked onto C:\
- installed python 2.7.6
- appended C:\python27 to the 'Path' environment variable
- installed MinGW v-0.6.2 mingw.org/download/installer
- inside MinGW Installation manager I included - [mingw32-base]
- appended C:\MinGW\bin to the 'Path' environment variable
- created file "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\distutils.cfg" containing:

  [build]

  compiler = mingw32

---------------  INCLUDING LIBAV libraries ---------------------------

- download pygtk-all-in-one-2.24.2.win32-py2.7.msi to get pkgconfig and all it's dependancies: ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pygtk/2.24/
- download libav win32 build win32.libav.org/win32/ and unpack into C:\libav\
- create a new environment variable name: "PKG_CONFIG_PATH" with the value at: C:\libav\usr\lib\pkgconfig
- append C:\libav\usr\bin\ to the 'Path' environment variable

-------------------- END LIBAV ---------------------------------------

- Inside the aubio path run the command: python .\waf configure build -j 1 --check-c-compiler=gcc
- I get a crash at 168/193 with test-delnull.exe but the build keeps going and returns "build" finished successfully
- Install numpy v-1.8.0 sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/
- Inside the aubio\python path run the command: python setup.py build
- Inside the aubio\python path run the command: python setup.py install
- I had to copy the dll from aubio\build\src\libaubio-4.dll into python27\Lib\site-packages\aubio\
- Then I added one of my own test.mp3 and test.wav files into aubio\python\tests\sounds\
- Inside the aubio\python\tests path I ran the command: python run_all_tests -v

------------------- EDIT ---------------------------------

The above instructions should work now without the problem originally asked

------------------- END EDIT -----------------------------

So from the results I get a lot of 'ok' regarding the many different tests being made however it's first problem is with "test_many_sinks" where it tries to use the .wav file from sounds and gives:

AUBIO ERROR: failed creating aubio source with [wav file path]

It continues giving the same error for the rest of the tests until it crashes on "test_zero_hop_size" and stops.

Any further advice as to what I still need to do would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from Paul Brossier we found out two issues:

1. Because I never included libav into my build I can't use .mp3's to test
2. Using a newer git repository ended up allowing me successfully run demo_bpm_extract.py which was previously erroring even when I tested with a .wav file.  The git source I used can be found here:  http://git.aubio.org/?p=aubio.git;a=commit;h=4a1378c12ffe7fd518448f6a1ab00f99f0557286

There are still quite a few errors showing up when executing "run_all_tests" which I've tried to pass over to Paul.